# How do I copy and rotate an object multiple times?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, inkscape, effects

I have an object that I want to "twist" like this:

[image: Several objects after each other]

I want to do the same with this picture.
[image: Single object]

I use both Inkscape and Photoshop.

Comment: Hi Morty, welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your question. Could you please show us what you have tried and why it didn't work or why you are discontent with the results? Please [edit] that info into your question. Please also have a look at the [tour](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help] to understand what Stack Exchange is about and how this site ticks. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question properly here are a few steps to rotate objects within a circular form:

1. Create your grid lines (one vertical, one horizontal)
2. Create your object (your object being the paddle)
3. Rasterize your object (it cannot be vector)
4. Select your object (CMD T) and move your center point to the area where the horizontal and vertical lines intersect
5. You will then rotate the shape - this will kind of tell photoshop what shape you want to make.
6. Then hold down CMD + Shift + Alt (Option) and hit the T button multiple times.
7. This will then give you a full 360 shape of the object

Hope this helps